# Two different login/lock screens

Tags: gnome, lightdm, 15.10, gdm

I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed and when I first start my computer it gives me the really nice looking ubuntu lightdm login screen but anytime I lock the computer I get the really nasty looking gnome lock screen. How can I make it only use one or the other?

Things I have tried:

- reinstalling GDM
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` on gdm and lightdm

`$ dm-tool lock` seems to lock correctly but pressing `super + L` takes me back to the ugly gdm lock screen.

My current workaround has been to change the keyboard shortcut to use `dm-tool lock` but that isn't really sustainable.

**Edit:**

Someone in the comments has suggested to remove the package `gdm` but when I try to it wants to remove `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and the list below. Clearly this isn't what I want to do.

```
account-plugin-aim account-plugin-google account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut account-plugin-yahoo acpi-support aisleriot
  app-install-data-partner apturl apturl-common argyll argyll-ref baobab bluez-cups brltty cheese dc dconf-editor deja-dup
  deja-dup-backend-cloudfiles deja-dup-backend-gvfs deja-dup-backend-s3 duplicity empathy empathy-common file-roller fonts-cantarell
  .....
  syslinux-legacy telepathy-gabble telepathy-idle telepathy-logger telepathy-salut toshset transmission-common transmission-gtk
  ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola ttf-indic-fonts-core ubuntu-sso-client unity-asset-pool uno-libs3 unoconv ure usb-creator-common
  usb-creator-gtk vino whoopsie x11-apps x11-session-utils xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdiagnose xinit xorg xsltproc yelp-tools zsync
```

Comment: Are you running `wallch`, the wallpaper change program? I'm not using 15.10, so this is just a suggestion of something to try.

Comment: I am not running that. However the background changes fine

Comment: I'm suggesting to try it. Can't hurt.

Comment: Why do you have GDM installed at all? You should have no trouble removing it (apt-get purge gdm3).

Comment: Remove `gdm`, that's all.

Comment: could be a quarrel between efi, uefi, insyde and bluefish ?! (joking a bit  ;o) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> is a shortcut set within Compiz window manager. What is being set in the settings goes into `gsettings` ( which is a framework for storring app settings, that's slightly different ) and then relays whatever shortcuts you set to `gnome-settings-daemon` or `unity-settings-daemon`.  That means we have to alter Compiz settings first.

The steps I personally took were as following:

1. Install compizconfig-settings-manager with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Open `compizconfig-settings-manager` with `ccsm` command form terminal or from dash's search
3. Under `Ubuntu Unity Plugin` option find `Key to lock screen` option, click on the button describing the shortcut.

You will see the a small popup window. Unckeck the `enabled` option.
[image]

At this point you can go to Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and set custom shortcuts with keybinding <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> as `dm-tool lock` command.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Trusty

**Edit**

Since OP is using Ubuntu Gnome and not Unity, I used my 15.10 Ubuntu Gnome virtual machine, and found that in a normal session there's no compiz processes running , however the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> appears to be hard codded within the gnome-shell itself.

What I've successfully achieved is the following : run  the `gsettings` command bellow and in the Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom  menu set custom shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to `dm-tool lock` command.

```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

After  running the command and creating shortcut, instead of the usual builtin gnome lock screen , I was able to use lightdm.  OP also confirmed this in our conversation in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33894/discussion-between-electrometro-and-serg) , but wanted <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to be the actual accelerator, and with better speed of locking. At the moment I am unable to address these issues, and it seems the key combination OP wants is hard-coded, hence unchangeable, but i am not 100% certain .

Comment: I am not using `Unity` so there is no section `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`

Comment: @electrometro First of you probably should have included that into your question. Your statement that you're using Ubuntu is a little bit misleading. `Ubuntu Gnome` would make more sense. Second, it really shouldn't matter, because with Ubuntu Gnome is also supposed to be using compiz,  and the Super+L shortcut should be hard coded into compiz, and calls appropriate dbus command.

Comment: My bad, I thought the `gnome` tag was enough. I installed Ubuntu server and then installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` package afterwards.

Comment: @electrometro I see. I've a virtual machine with the same package installed. I'll investigate some more, see what i can do.

Comment: In response to a comment earlier, I don't have `gdm3` installed. Rather, I have just `gdm`.

Comment: @electrometro come to the [AskUbuntu Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33894/discussion-between-electrometro-and-serg).